# DateTime from XLS to C# conversion failure

Tags: c#, excel, date, type-conversion

I'm working on VS2008 .NET3.5 with a Office 2003 doc (.xls). I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to access to a document.

This works fine for my purpose but fails whenever I try to get a Date.

The way I'm using is the most common:

```
object date= xlWorkSheet.get_Range("E" + i, "E" + i).Value2;
double doubleDate = double.Parse(date);
DateTime finallyDate = DateTime.FromOADate(doubleDate);
```

The date I have stored is 01/12/1961 (in Italian means first december and if I open excel it tolds me 1 december 1961).

When I run my app it happens that the value of the double become 15011.0 and when the finallyDate value is 2/4/1941 that's not right!

How can I solve this problem? Is there any way to convert (also manually) that 15011 number?

Thank you!!

Comment: What exactly is the value of `date` itself, before you parse it? (I'm surprised the above code even compiles, given that `date` is declared to be an `object`...)

Comment: @JonSkeet With Excel Interop (before C#4 where you can use dynamic) I think that everything is returned as an object. To use anything other than an object on the left side of your assignment operator, you need to cast it as needs be on the right side

Comment: @JMK: Sure, I'm fine with the first statement - but there's no `double.Parse(object)` method...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I didn't see that, I just tested it and you are of course right, it doesn't compile!

Comment: The value of the cell is: 12/1/1961..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the Value property instead of Value2, then you will be able to work with a Date object. You may need to cast it as (DateTime).

What you get instead with Value2 is the floating point value of the Date.

For example, check out my spreadsheet below, where A1 contains a date:

[image: Spreadsheet]

Then in Excel, I add my reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, and grab the Value and Value2 properties like so:

```
var excel = new Excel.Application();

var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Test\Test.xlsx");
var worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];

Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A1");

var rangeAsValue = range.Value;
var rangeAsValue2 = range.Value2;

Console.WriteLine(rangeAsValue);
Console.WriteLine(rangeAsValue2);

Console.ReadLine();
```

I get this output:

[image: Output]

Interestingly, if you try this in a .Net 4.5 application, it still works but the type of `var` is resolved as dynamic for `rangeAsValue` and `rangeAsValue2`, and you lose your intellisense.

Comment: Hi! I'm using Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library... With you code I can't see Value but only Value2!

Comment: I am using the 12.0 library also, and targeting .net 3.5 client framework and this works for me. The only using Statement I have needed to add is `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Comment: Dunno why but it still won't gimme the date but some number... :(

Answer (score 0):

To the first part of your question, *How can I solve this problem?*

Do ensure

1. Document is saved.
2. You are accessing the right cell.

To your second part of the question, *Is there any way to convert (also manually) that 15011 number?*

The 15011 is actually the number of days from 1-1-1900. I usually just divide the mentioned number by 365 to get a *rough* date. You will be asking why rough? Because we need to take leap year into consideration when some years have 366 days.

If you need an accurate calculation of the date with the serial number, you might want to use the method found here. http://naspinski.net/post/Translate-an-Excel-Serial-Date-into-a-C-DateTime.aspx

```
public DateTime ExcelSerialDateToDT(int nSerialDate)
 {
 int l = nSerialDate + 68569 + 2415019;
 int n = ((4 * l) / 146097);
 l = l - ((146097 * n + 3) / 4);
 int i = ((4000 * (l + 1)) / 1461001);
 l = l - ((1461 * i) / 4) + 31;
 int j = ((80 * l) / 2447);
 int nDay = l - ((2447 * j) / 80);
 l = (j / 11);
 int nMonth = j + 2 - (12 * l);
 int nYear = 100 * (n - 49) + i + l;

return DateTime.Parse(nMonth + "/" + nDay + "/" + nYear);
 }
```

You can read more on why this behavior on Microsoft Office Excel on
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2750/Excel-serial-date-to-Day-Month-Year-and-vise-versa

Comment: Hi.. The document is saved and I'm accessing the right cell..
If I use the code you propose I get the same wrong date I get from excel.. I get 2/4/1941 intstea of 12/1/1961

Comment: The above is a rather poor version of what the static DateTime.FromOADate() does